# Sansa Clip Zip does not mount

Tags: 13.04, mp3, sansa-clip

My Sansa Clip Zip MP3 player (uses USB) does not mount. I am new to Ubuntu so I'm not sure how to proceed when it says:

```
unable to open device '[usb:001,011]'
```

Answer (score 8):

According to [this community entry](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SansaClip) you just need to go to "settings > system > usb mode" and select "MSC". Just do this in my player and it now visible in ubuntu.

Looks like MTP live in parallel to MSC so don't be confused when you will not see any files copied from Windows machine.

Version of firmware on my player is 1.1.20. There is a chance that you should [update firmware](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6932/) to find usb option

Answer (score 0):

the way you can automount your gadget is installing gvfs, using synaptic package manager or anyone else. most of the made-in-china stuff use mtp protocol, so you can mount it installing the addin suppoorting that

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the player to MSC mode as described in the answer by Meta, you should try using another USB cable. I wouldn't believe it if I hadn't seen it myself, but when using a cable other than the short one that came with the player, it kept disconnecting.

Answer (score 0):

What I did just now was going to "Settings" --> "System Settings" --> "USB Mode" --> "MTP"

If you do this, you will be able to see Sandisk as a USB device through your Ubuntu file manager (Nautilus, Thunar, etc.).

If you use the "MSC" mode, you will detect the device but cannot see the files inside "Music"

Answer (score 0):

Still an issue in *buntu distros version 16.04 LTS for SanDisk "Sansa".
Wawan Yulianto's work-around still succeeds.
So does setting the SanDisk USB Mode to MSC which provides a different view of the same content.  Just do not use a USB Mode of "Auto Detect".